# gcc/ld: undefined reference to unused function

Tags: gcc, cygwin, ld

I'm using gcc 4.3.4 and ld 2.20.51 in Cygwin under Windows 7.  Here's a simplified version of my problem:

- `foo.o` contains function `foo_bar()` which calls `bar()` in bar.o
- `bar.o` contains function `bar()`
- `main.c` calls functions in `foo.o`, but `foo_bar()` is not in the call chain

If I try to compile main.c and link it to foo.o, I get an `undefined reference to _foo_bar` error from ld.  As you can see from my Makefile except below, I've tried using flags for putting each function in its own section and having the linker discard unused sections.

```
COMPILE_CYGWIN = gcc -iquote$(INCDIR)
COMPILE = $(COMPILE_CYGWIN) -g -MMD -MP -Wall -ffunction-sections -Wl,-gc-sections $(DEFINE)
main_OBJECTS = main.o foo.o
main.exe : $(main_OBJECTS)
    $(COMPILE) -o main.exe $(main_OBJECTS)
```

The function `foo_bar()` is a short function that provides a connection between two networking layers in a protocol stack.  Some programs don't need it, so they won't link in the other object files related to the upper layer of the stack.  It's a small function, and seems inappropriate to put it into its own .o file.

I don't understand why ld throws the error -- nothing is calling `foo_bar()`, so there's no need to include `bar()` in the final executable.  A coworker has just told me that `ld` is not a "smart linker", so maybe what I'm trying to do isn't possible?

Comment: `-ffunction-sections` would have been needed when compiling `foo`.  Is there any particular problem with linking against `bar` also?

Comment: In this case, linking in `bar.o` requires at least 15 more object files to fill its dependencies.  I think I've reached a point where I need to be linking the object files into a library and having my programs reference that instead.

Comment: Unless you have other constraints, it's not as bad as it sounds.  It's a little up front pain but it won't have any significant run-time cost.  I don't know how the dynamic linker on Windows works, but assuming it's half decent, that extraneous code will never be loaded anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless the linker is from [Cyberdyne Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyberdyne_Systems) it has no way to know exactly which functions will actually be called. It only knows which ones are *referenced*.  Even [Skynet's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skynet_%28Terminator%29) linker can't predict what run-time decisions will be made or what will happen if you load a module dynamically at run-time and it starts calling various global functions<sup>1</sup>.

So, *if* you link in module *m* and it references function *f*, you will need to link with whatever module has *f*.

---

<sup>1. This problem is related to the *[Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)* and has been proven *[undecidable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem)*.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I hit the similar issue and I find this page:
http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-utils/2004-09/msg00098.html
Highligt:
The GNU linker still works at .o file granularity.
Gcc pulls in foo.o and then find bar() was undefined.

You'd better put foo_bar() into another .o file.